# Cloning codes from two repositories and replacing the codes but IOS folder is not pushed into the github

Tags: ios, flutter, github

I'm cloning the github code of a project and copying the code files. further I get a clone of the same project but older version from a remote repository and replace those files with earlier copied version of the code. Further I push the code to remote repository. While doing this process the files in the IOS folder are not pushed in remote repository. Earlier few days back I've done the same process the files are pushed correctly and files of IOS folder pushed too. (Note: none of the above mentioned repositories are linked to my VSCode)
Could anyone give the steps for this, i'am new to coding and git hub ?

Could anyone give the steps for this issue, i'am new to coding and git hub ?

Comment: Probably the .gitignore file was edited. Can you please provide the content of that file, from both remote and local repo?